# I'm trying to echo a MySQLi SELECT SUM query result in PHP but it doesn't echo the result

Tags: php, mysqli

This is the query:

```
$querySum = "SELECT SUM(realcost)FROM checking-apartments ";
$result1 = mysqli_query($link, $querySum);
```

And this is where I try to echo it:

```
echo'<table id="tableSum">';
while($row = $result1->fetch_array())
{
echo '<td style="padding-left:1200px; font-weight:bold;">Total Estimated Costs: ' . $row['$result1'] . '</td>
<td style="font-weight:bold;">Total Real Costs: ' . $row['$result1'] . '</td>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: you need to display like $row['realcost']

Comment: Sorry that doesn't work either.

Comment: just check var_dump($row) inside the while loop

Comment: $row['SUM(realcost)'] will be the Default Name, at least for me.

Comment: You are both right but it still doesn't show anything. Only the 'Total Estimated Costs:'.

Comment: Solved the problem thanks for the help guys!